# Update Component B when there's an update in Component A

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario where there are 2 Dropdowns (Inside a parent component), let them be named A and B.
When Dropdown-A is updated by the user, Dropdown-B's **options** and **selected value** should also be changed.

Eg.

State at T1

```
Dropdown-A
Options: [1,2]
Selected: 1
```

```
Dropdown-B
Options: [X,Y]
Selected: X
```

Now, user changed the value of Dropdown-A from let's say 1 to 2

State at T2:

```
Dropdown-A
Options: [1,2]
Selected: 2
```

```
Dropdown-B
Options: [P,Q]
Selected: Q
```

Now the way I am trying to achieve this is, inside the `onUpdate` of Dropdown-A I am updating the "**List of Options**" and **"selected value for Dropdown-B"** in the state of the parent component (these values are then passed down to Dropdown-B as props).

**Issue**

Dropdown-B does not find the "Selected value" inside the "options" list which is passed.
Now the reason for this is the "new options list" is still getting passed down to the component but the "Selected value" prop has reached first. Hence it is not able to find the selected value inside the options-list.

and this leads to **console error**

**How should I solve this?**

P.s. I was thinking if some mechanism exists through which I can make sure that Dropdown-1 gets the Options-list prop first, renders/apply the logic and then the selected-value prop is sent

*** Code snippet ***

```
const optionsListFromDropdownB = useMemo(
  () => getCurrencies(currentMerchantAccount),
  [getCurrencies, currentMerchantAccount]
);

<Dropdown
  name={'Dropdown-A'}
  onUpdate={(merchantAccountId): void => {
      // update dropdownBValue
      setValueDropdownB(getDefault(merchantAccountId));
  }}
  value={currentMerchantAccount} // this currentMerchantAccount gets updated by the Dropdown, using Form context
  options={DropdownAOptions}
/>

<Dropdown
  name={'Dropdown-B'}
  options={currenciesMemoized}
  value={dropdownBValue}
/>
```

Comment: The *issue* you describe, is how you interpret it. Why not post your code, and give us a chance to our own interpretation?

Comment: Exactly, I don't think the timing is the issue here. Even if the props don't change at the same time, each change will force a re-render, so the order doesn't matter. As soon as the second prop change happens, the component should render correctly.

Comment: I agree, I have tried posting the code in a way that could be understood. Please let me know if it is still creating confusion? the issue is that I am getting the console error from Dropdown-2 saying that the Selected value does not exists in the options-list.

Comment: Are you changing dropdown 2's selected value when dropdown 1 is changed? Because changing just the options is obviously not enough. Here's a short demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-turing-flq1t?file=/src/App.js Also, you're using `options={currenciesMemoized}` but in your snippet it's `optionsListFromDropdownB` first?